# Oscillation of a particle on a parabolic surface [equation of motion]

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I have a particle on a parabolic surface $y = Ax^2$ and I have to show that the frequency is $$\omega = \sqrt{2Ag}$$

By using polar coordinates $F = ma = -mg \sin \theta = mR\ddot{\theta}$

$-mg\sin\theta = F_{\phi}$ is the only force in the movement direction, right?

Because this is not a circle I can't use $R$ as radius, so I should replace $R$ for something else, but I don't figure out.

I have to get the equation of motion  $$\ddot{\theta} + 2Ag \theta = 0$$

thus, $2Ag = \omega^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem where knowledge of energy could is useful.

Assuming that the gravitational potential energy vanishes $U=0$ at $y=0$, we have a gravitational potential energy of $U(y) = m g y = m g (A x^2) = (mgA) x^2$. One might realize that this potential is similar to a spring's potential energy $(1/2)k x^2$ where x in this case is a displacement from a springs rest length.

For a spring the frequency is $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. We can see analogously, our "k" is $2 m g A$ so the frequency is $\sqrt{\frac{2 m g A}{m}} = \sqrt{2 g A} $.